# Undefinded props

Tags: reactjs, routes

When I add parameter (:id) to route path I can't get prop: "option". In Dashboard class component this.props.option is undefinded, why?   In other component I have prop "option"

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render( 
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
     <Route path={Config.pathDef + "dashboard,panel"} element={<Dashboard option="1"/>}   /> 
     <Route path={Config.pathDef + "dashboard,details,item,:id"} element={<Dashboard option="2"/>}   /> 
     <Route path={Config.pathDef + "dashboard,details"} element={<Dashboard option="2"/>}   /> 
     <Route path={Config.pathDef + "dashboard,search"} element={<Dashboard option="3"/>}   />  
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `element` property of each `Route`, and add your component inside the `Route` tags:

```
<Route path={Config.pathDef + "dashboard,panel"}>
  <Dashboard option="1" />
</Route>
```